# How to do a truncate statement on multiple database at once using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, truncate

How to do a truncate statement on multiple database at once using SQL Server?

Comment: How many tables are we talking?

Comment: "...at once..." If doing this in parallel is important (and given how fast a truncate is, I can't imagine why it would be) you could use SSIS. Are the databases all on the same server?

Comment: **200-800 table for each database,  DB size 90G, 20G, 120G**

The script includes the following 
**and table_name like 't_%'**
and table_name not like 't_ref_%'
and table_name not like 't_co_processhistory_archive'

Comment: **Yes, there are in different servers**, I am happy to do a server at time, if there is away.

Answer (score 2):

"a truncate statement"... "at once"

It's not possible to run a single statement that will truncate multiple tables on multiple databases at once.

Closest thing to it is restoring a backup of a clean (all tables empty) copy of the database.   And even that will have to be done once per database.

Answer (score 0):

Below statement will take care of loop through all db's and look for one particular table and truncate the data.

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb 'use ?; if exists (select ''x'' from sysobjects where name =''test1'' ) TRUNCATE TABLE TEST1'
```